# Поля начинающиеся с знака подчеркивания

Tags: php, yii

Просто интересно:
В yii часть полей класса носят имена вида

```
public $_files;
public $_name;
```

Другие без подчёркивания

```
public $db;
```

В чём разницы?
Поля отмеченные нижней чертой это метаданные?

Comment: а откуда выдраны эти поля?

Comment: @IVsevolod из контекста :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Обычно с подчеркивания начинаются protected переменные. К этим переменным принято писать сеттер и геттер, т.к. из вне доступа к ним нет.

Пример:

```
protected $_name;

public function getName()
{
    return $this->_name;
}

public function setName($name)
{
    $this->_name = $name;
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Только не `return #this;`, а `return $this;`
:-)

Comment: не только protected, но и private =)

Comment: Чуть дополню. Это с 4 PHP пошло, когда не было еще модификаторов доступа, и таким образом их определяли, чтобы визуально видеть, что к чему относится. Ну а теперь уже это просто кто-то по привычке использует.

Comment: И я тоже чуть-чуть дополню: это не только в пхп, например,в питоне это общепринятая практика для protected-переменных (позволяет избежать name mangling'a), в сишарпе зачастую так именуют холдеры свойств (свойство в сишарпе - это геттер и сеттер, очень похоже на вышеописанную ситуацию, но там все хитрее).

Вообще, чем глубже я копаю Yii и C#, тем явнее для меня становится факт, что Yii на самом деле не PHP-шники пишут.

Comment: @aldem67 еще чуток дополню :) для некоторых фреймворков (пр Zend Framework 1) это еще и принятый стандарт кодирования

Comment: @Johny поправил